# -webkit-text-size-adjust not working on iPad OS 13

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, ios13, dynamic-type-feature

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <body>
                <div style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 56.2962293624878%;">
                    Sample text sample text sample text
                </div>
                <div style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 156.2962293624878%;">
                    Sample text sample text sample text
                </div>
                <div style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 356.2962293624878%;">
                    Sample text sample text sample text
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

As described in https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201404, -webkit-text-size-adjust is not working on iPad running iOS 13. Any idea what can be used as a replacement for this? I'm using webkit-text-size-adjust to handle dynamic types ([1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically?language=objc)).

Comment: Ähhm, what about `font-size` ?

Comment: As explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size, percentage in font-size corresponds to the parent element's font-size. webkit-text-size-adjust , however, corresponds to the same element's initial font size ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust ). I'm using webkit-text-size-adjust to handle dynamic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebKit has fixed the issue. See - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212122.

Note that preferredContentMode should be set to WKContentMobile ->
webViewConfiguration.defaultWebpagePreferences.preferredContentMode = WKContentModeMobile